# How to group by based on equilibrium values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have Source Table Demo,Sum(Value) is 213

```
ID          Name                                               Value
----------- -------------------------------------------------- -----------
1           A                                                  10
2           A                                                  15
3           A                                                  20
4           A                                                  50
5           B                                                  10
6           B                                                  15
7           B                                                  20
8           C                                                  10
9           C                                                  20
10          C                                                  43
```

It is necessary to divide the sum of the Value column into the specified number of groups and prioritize the merging of the Name column

Like so:

Result 1(3 Group),Sum(Value) is 213,Group average value is 71

```
ID          Name                                               Value       GroupNum
----------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- -----------
1           A                                                  10          1
2           A                                                  15          1
3           A                                                  20          2
4           A                                                  50          2
5           B                                                  10          1
6           B                                                  15          1
7           B                                                  20          1
8           C                                                  10          3
9           C                                                  20          3
10          C                                                  43          3
```

In Result 1

Group 1 Sum Value is 70 and contain Name(A,B)

Group 2 Sum Value is 70 and Name column only A

Group 3 Sum Value is 73 and Name column only B

Result 2(4 Group),Sum(Value) is 213,Group average value is 53.25

```
ID          Name                                               Value       GroupNum
----------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- -----------
1           A                                                  10          1
2           A                                                  15          1
3           A                                                  20          1
4           A                                                  50          2
5           B                                                  10          1
6           B                                                  15          3
7           B                                                  20          3
8           C                                                  10          4
9           C                                                  20          3
10          C                                                  43          4
```

In Result 2

Group 1 Sum Value is 55 and contain Name(A,B)

Group 2 Sum Value is 50 and Name column only B

Group 3 Sum Value is 55 and contain Name(B,C)

Group 4 Sum Value is 53 and Name column only C

The number of groups can be specified, such as dividing into 2 groups or any number of groups.

How to obtain Result 1 and Result 2 through SQL?

Comment: What you're looking for is a variation of a knapsack problem, of which there are a lot of solutions. it will not perform well for larger datasets

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic T-SQL approach for combinatorics/knapsack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28202429/dynamic-t-sql-approach-for-combinatorics-knapsack)

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL are *completely* different products and the solutions for one could be completely different for the other. Rather than asking for solution for both focus on one. Then, if you are struggling to translate the solution to the other dialect, as a new question.

Comment: yep,my question is a variation of a knapsack problem,The Dynamic T-SQL approach for combinatorics/knapsack be helpful,But it's very different from my question

Comment: @ThomA Both MySQL and SQL Server solutions are available,I can translate it.