Max QTY with price <= 100 (Query)



Name
Price
Qty




A
3
30


B
5
3


C
5
3


D
6
20



i have a table contain data like this. i want to get what is the maximum of sum(qty) that i can provide Price <= 100
expected output : 32
coming from : 30 qty A and 2 qty from B or C

the given table is just one of the example test case. the other test case even have more rows

Please show us what you've tried. You can do this with a running total.

Which column provides the ordering for taking prices?

@TimBiegeleisen They want the maximum quantity, so go from lowest price to highest.

This type of problem is not amenable to a SQL solution for the general case. Lookup approaches to solving knapsack problems. There is a post with a procedural approach using T-SQL at (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28202429/dynamic-t-sql-approach-for-combinatorics-knapsack).

Hi @Schwern actually im not familiar with iterating/looping in SQL the last thing im trying is brute forcing the query and ya it will not work in other cases just work with this cases. but thanks for the suggestion i will try

Hi @JohnH thanks for the suggestion

SQL only is not the good language for that, use any programming language to loop on different cases. T-SQL, but also, python, java, dot net, C, Rust, go...

This can be solved by using a recursive common table expression to calculate a running total. I have used an initial cte to expand your data to one row per item (30 rows for item A, 3 rows for item B, etc) and have ordered these by cost. The recursive part of the query the loops through each of these in order until the total price reaches 100.
create table t (
    name varchar not null,
    price integer not null,
    qty integer not null
    );

insert into t (name, price, qty) values('A', 3, 30), ('B', 5, 3), ('C', 5, 3), ('D', 6, 20);

with recursive expanded as (
    select name, price, row_number() over(order by price, name)
    from t
    cross join generate_series(1, qty)
    ),
purchased (name, remaining, next_row_number) as (
    select null::text, 100, 1::bigint
    union all
    select expanded.name, purchased.remaining - expanded.price, expanded.row_number + 1
    from purchased
    join expanded on expanded.row_number = purchased.next_row_number
    where expanded.price <= purchased.remaining
    )
select count(name) as qty
from purchased;


First, get a rolling sum of quantity and price * quantity. Use a window ordered by price to ensure you spend your money on the best deals first. Since price is not unique, we can also order by the primary key (I'm using name) to ensure consistent results.
Use lead to keep track of the next possible option, price, and available quantity.
  select
    name,
    price,
    qty,
    sum(qty) over w as "running purchased",
    sum(price * qty) over w as "running cost",
    lead(name) over w as "next option",
    lead(price) over w as "next price",
    lead(qty) over w as "next option"
  from items
  window w as (order by price, name asc rows unbounded preceding)

At this point we have all the information we need to finish the calculation.

Pick the first row closest to, but not over, your limit.
100 - "running cost" is the "remaining money"
floor( "remaining money" / "next price" ) is the "next purchased"
"next price" * "next purchased" is the "next cost"
100 - "running cost" - "next cost" is the "remaining money"

It might be easier to do the final calculation outside of SQL using the results, or you can finish up in SQL...
Use a CTE to pick the row closest to, but not over, your limit and calculate how many can be purchased with your remainder.
Finally, use another CTE to sum this all up and calculate how much money is left over.
with running_total as (
  select
    name,
    price,
    qty,
    sum(qty) over w as "running purchased",
    sum(price * qty) over w as "running cost",
    lead(name) over w as "next option",
    lead(price) over w as "next price",
    lead(qty) over w as "next option"
  from items
  window w as (order by price, name asc rows unbounded preceding)
),
final_purchase as (
  select 
    *, 
    floor( (100 - "running cost") / "next price" ) as "next purchased"
  from running_total
  where "running cost" <= 100
)
select
  *,
  "next purchased" * "next price" as "next cost",
  "running purchased" + "next purchased" as "total purchased",
  "running cost" + ("next purchased" * "next price") as "total spent",
  100 - ("running cost" + ("next purchased" * "next price")) as "remaining money"
from final_purchase

This might have performance advantages over a recursive approach.
Demonstration.
